# convert byte[] from json in android

Tags: android, json

how to get byte[] from json using webservice

My json format is given below:

```
     [{"imgLogo":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,219,0,132,0,
    9,6,7,20,19,18,20,20,19,20,21,22,20,22,20,21,24,22,21,21,20,20,20,20,20,
    24,21,20,22,24,20,20,20,23,24,28,40,32,24,26,37,28,20,
    21,33,49,33,37,41,43,46,46,46,23,31,51,56,51,44,55,40,45,46,43,1,10,10,10
    ,14,13,14,27,16,16,26,44,36,28,36,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,
    44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,
    44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,255,192,0,17,8,0,194,1,3,3....]}]
```

I'm using this following code to get json value like this :

```
 JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
 String imagestring = jsonChildNode.getString("imgLogo");
```

Now, I'm getting above byte[] value as string. then how can I convert this string to byte[]

Answer (score 0):

first create a String containing your data and then

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(iconString, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

now you have byte array containing your bitmap.

Comment: i already using this code but i get the following error.           11-15 03:41:11.353: D/decodedString(1376): [B@b3e9fa50
11-15 03:41:11.353: D/skia(1376): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
11-15 03:41:11.353: I/System.out(1376): Bitmap photo : null

Answer (score 0):

Use this `getBytes` method :

```
byte[] bytes = imagestring .getBytes("UTF-8");
```